my nested query OR conditions replace by AND in laravel sql code
i create a nested query like this in laravel 10 :
$product->where(function ($query) use ($values) { $query->orWhereIn('properties.value', $values); }

here is the problem :
when i use $product->where (AND) , the $query->orWhereIn (OR) change to $query->whereIn (AND) by itselt (in results , in sql code)
when i use $product->orWhere , the $query->whereIn change to $query->orWhereIn by itselt (in results , in sql code)
it change my $query->orWhereIn (OR) condition to what ever $product->where (AND) is
i want $product->where and $query->orWhereIn inside it but laravel create a sql code with $query->whereIn !
it create a AND condition from my $query->orWhereIn code !!!!
how can i use $query->orWhereIn inside $product->where ?!?!?!?

why have you wrapped a single where condition in a closure? as such it does not matter at all if the inner condition is AND or OR. In this case the outer where would determine how your condition interacts with the rest of the query

i want $product->where and $query->orWhereIn inside - can you write the how you expect such SQL to be like?

@kris-gjika it can be multi condition !

like this :
$product->where(function ($query) use ($values) {
$query->orWhereIn('properties.value', $values);
$query->orWhereIn('properties.value', $values2);
}

i have products and properties . example : i select product with title and price and it have 4 properties . two of them can be "option 1" OR "option 2" . so properties can be diffrent in a properties table

@QasemSalehy If there is another where query associated with it, then orWhereIn would make sense. It makes sense, in my opinion, to query about anything like this or that. To me, asking or that alone doesn't make sense.


I have products and properties. Example: I select product with title and price and it have 4 properties. Two of them can be "option 1" OR "option 2".  So properties can be different in a properties table.

You could form your query like:
$product->where(function ($query) use ($priceValues, $titles) {
    $query->whereIn('properties.title', $titles) /* Change this to your context */
          ->orWhereIn('properties.price', $priceValues);
})

